# How to create dropdown menu for the following code in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, html-select

Consider an HTML list of links:

```
<a href="/d_population/1">User 1 name link</a><br>   
<a href="/d_population/2">User 2 name link</a><br>
```

This code generates the list:

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to user.name + " link", d_population_path(user.id) %><br>   
<% end %>
```

The relevant route is:

```
match 'd_population/:this_client', :to => 'dashboard#population', :as => 'd_population'
```

I would like to use an HTML dropdown to make the same HTTP request.

Is it possible to use a dropdown to make a HTTP request that looks like `/d_population/1`?

I attempted to use `form_tag` and `select_tag` to generate the dropdown and pass `this_client` as a parameter, but kept getting routing errors. Do you need to add a route `d_population/` to make a dropdown work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are a few resources to help you get started with Dropdowns and Menu's

Tabs on Rails is an awesome Gem that will help you generate Li menu's in Rails http://www.simonecarletti.com/code/tabs_on_rails/

Bootstrap is a UI Framework, developed by Twitter http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

I've successfully implemented both of these in a current project that i've been working on.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know there were gems to help with dropdowns. Knowing that they actually worked for you is very helpful.

Comment: Jasdeep, can you please explain what was needed for integration of tabs_on_rails with bootstrap.

Comment: justin, if you want I can push my code to my GitHub profile for you?